# SAS: Compute value of column under an ACROSS variable (Nested/Derived/Pseudo-Column)

Tags: sas

I can't seem to include a computed variable in a PROC REPORT. It works fine when the computed variable is a headline column, but when it forms part of an ACROSS group, I can't get it to work. I've only got so far as to be able to reference the columns direcly, which only gives me the result for a single ACROSS group, not both.

```
data have1;
   input username $  betdate : datetime. stake winnings winner;
   dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
   format betdate DATETIME.;
   format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
   datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 90 -90 0
    player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 100 40 1
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 120 -120 0
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:00 50 15 1
    player1 05NOV2008:09:05:00 30 5 1
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20 10 1
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 10 -10 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:40 15 -15 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:45 15 -15 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:45 15 45 1
    player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 -35 0
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 1
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 1
run;

PROC PRINT; RUN;

Proc rank data=have1 ties=mean out=ranksout1 groups=2;
     var    stake winner;
     ranks  stakeRank winnerRank;
run;

PROC REPORT DATA=ranksout1 NOWINDOWS out=report;
    COLUMN stakerank winnerrank, (N stake=stakemean discountedstake);
    DEFINE stakerank / GROUP '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE winnerrank / ACROSS '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE stake / analysis sum noprint;
    DEFINE stakemean / analysis sum;
    DEFINE discountedstake / computed format=8.2 'discountedstake';
    COMPUTE discountedstake;
        _C4_ = _C3_ -1;
    ENDCOMP;
RUN;
```

I don't understand how a variable connected to an across group can be calculated. This only calculates the value of 'discountedstake' for column '*C4*' and it doesn't make sense to do it again for column 7.

How can I include the value of that computed variable in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PROC REPORT DATA=ranksout1 NOWINDOWS out=report;
    COLUMN stakerank winnerrank, (N stake=stakemean discountedstake);
    DEFINE stakerank / GROUP '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE winnerrank / ACROSS '' ORDER=INTERNAL;
    DEFINE stake / analysis sum noprint;
    DEFINE stakemean / analysis sum;
    DEFINE discountedstake / computed format=8.2 'discountedstake';
    COMPUTE discountedstake;
    _C4_ = _C3_ -1;
    _C7_ = _C6_ -1;
    ENDCOMP;
RUN;
```

You just need to mention each column you want calculated.  You might be able to do this with an array if you have many of them, or do it in a data step/view ahead of time.